# Select first unique value in table

Tags: sql, oracle, plsql

I am looking for SQL how to select first unique value in table for column OBJID. What I would like to have is result, where just first existence of OBJID (group by) or (distinct) didn't work. As well I have searched everywhere, but couldn't find working solution for this. Does anybody have a idea how to have result where every OBJID would be just once with their values from row.

```
OBJID   OTHER   YEAR    TYPE        OBJID   OTHER   YEAR    TYPE
AA      4       2001    e36         AA      4       2001    e36
AA      5       2001    e36                 
AA      6       2001    e38                 
BB      7       2001    e38         BB      7       2001    e38
CC      8       2001    e38         CC      8       2001    e38
DD      9       2001    e38         DD      9       2001    e38
EE      10      2001    e38         EE      10      2001    e38
FF      11      2001    e38         FF      11      2001    e38
GG      12      2001    e39         GG      12      2001    e39
HH      1       2001    e39         HH      1       2001    e39
HH      1       2001    e39                 
HH      1       2001    e39                 
II      1       2001    e39         II      1       2001    e39
II      2       2001    e39                 
JJ      1       2001    e39         JJ      1       2001    e39
JJ      2       2001    e39                 
KK      1       2001    e39         KK      1       2001    e39
KK      2       2001    e39                 
KK      2       2001    e39                 
KK      3       2001    e39
```

So there is 20 rows of inputs and I want just unique for every OBJID so 11 rows of output which will work with ORACLE SQL. Any help or direction would be really appreciated. Thanks.

Comment: How do you define "first"?

Comment: I don't care which of the row will be selected for the same occurrence of the OBJID I just need one. So for example you have First AA which is there 3 times but every OTHER is different and you have there HH which is there as well 3 times but all lines are same and I need just one for any of them.

Comment: @Peter - Gordon's answer is the solution. You can use column "other" in the order by clause.

Comment: I have tried but gives me - ORA-00923: FROM keyword not found where expected
00923. 00000 -  "FROM keyword not found where expected"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think this should do

```
wITH temptab AS (                                                
    SELECT a.OBJID, a.OTHER, a.YEAR, a.type,                     
           ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION BY a.OBJID ORDER BY OTHER) AS rnumber    
      FROM table1  a)                                            
SELECT x.*                                                       
FROM temptab x                                                   
 WHERE x.rnumber = 1
```

Comment: uSeruSher thanks I got it wrong. This works. Thank you very much really appreciate.

Comment: maybe one more question. Can I create a table from this result , so it would be visible and stored somewhere with for example with that temptab name. Thanks

Comment: yes, i guess it works as ......select x.OBJID, x.OTHER, x.YEAR, x.type into newtable from......

Comment: Not fully follow . Could you maybe please write the whole code for it please. Because I have tried to put on start and on end and no luck :)

Comment: just add "INTO table name" after your cloumn names in Select clause.

Comment: Yes I guess that could work in PLSQL but not in my SQL Oracle Developer , because I got error message even when I try **SELECT * INTO tableNew FROM tableOld**

Answer (score 1):

You would use `row_number()` in Oracle.  But you need to specify what you mean by "first":

```
select t.*
from (select t.*,
             row_number() over (partition by objid order by ?? asc) as seqnum
      from t
     ) t
where seqnum = 1;
```

You need to specify the column or columns that define the first row, in the `order by`.  Replace the `??`.

Comment: ORA-00923: FROM keyword not found where expected
00923. 00000 -  "FROM keyword not found where expected"

Comment: @PeterKepo . . . There is nothing in this query that would generate that error.